# AngularJS actualizar registro en base de datos desde form

Tags: angularjs, base-de-datos, formularios

Necesito la lógica para guardar correctamente o actualizar(POST) un conjunto de registros. Usando este resource que llama a la base de datos.

```
TripResource.updateTrip = function(id,ship){
    return $http.put(URL + '/trips'+'/'+id, trip);
    // .success(function(data, status, headers, config){

    // })
};
```

Entiendo que se tendría que meter dentro de una función en el controlador,para esa función meterla en el botón de Save en un ng-click... Pero la funcion espera un id y un trip con la info de todo el objeto.
Se tambien que tengo que declarar un objeto vacio como:

`$scope.updateTrip={};`

Pero como se le mandan los valores del form a ese objeto?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, para poder tomar los datos de un form, podés usar ng-model:

Html:

```
<form>
  <label for="">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="" value="" ng-model='nombre'/>

  <label for="">Apellido</label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="" value="" ng-model='apellido'/>

  <button ng-click='guardar()'>Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.guardar= function(){
    servicio.setNombres({nombre: $scope.nombre, apellido: $scope.apellido}).then(function(data){
      $scope.ultimoId = data.data;
    });
  }
```

Servicio:

```
function setNombres(valor){
    return $http.post('/nombres', valor)
    .then(function(response){ return response; })
    .catch(function(response){ return response; });
  }
```

En este plnkr lo podés ver funcionando: http://plnkr.co/edit/nh5ZQm5UWD7gFpIX5GD1?p=preview

El servicio de backend está simulado para que puedas recibir una respuesta.

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, y no dudes en volver a preguntar en caso contrario. Saludos